# printglossary makes abbreviations ending with periods

Tags: formatting, glossaries, acronyms

I use the `glossaries` package for my glossary and some acronyms:

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,section]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

...

/% Glossary
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossar]

/% Acronyms
\deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Akronyme}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]
```

Curiously, glossaries makes a period after each acronym.

**Screnshot:**

[image]

How can you change that?

Comment: Use the `nopostdot` package option

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just as **cgnieder** has said, you have to use the `nopostdot` option.

**Example:**

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronym,toc,section]{glossaries}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=super]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As a general rule it is better to explain your solution at little:)