# How to remove a dot and a page number in the environment 'glossaries'

Tags: glossaries

How to remove **a dot** and **a page number** in the environment `glossaries`? See the picture below - the yellow mark.

Thanks for help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a5paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{glossaries} 

%----------------------------------------------- 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\ballnumber}[1]{\tikz \node[circle,fill=.,inner sep=1pt,anchor=south] {\color{-.}\bfseries #1};} 


% GLOSS 
%-----------------------------------------------
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{to catch}
{
  name={ to catch },
  description={ [\textipa{k\ae tS}] $\bullet$ \textbf{caught} [\textipa{kO:t}] $\bullet$ \textbf{caught} [\textipa{kO:t}] $\blacktriangleleft$ {\tiny \ballnumber{1}} chytať, dochytať \textit{čo (rukami)}  }
}


\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy


\gls{to catch} 
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Package options `nopostdot` and `nonumberlist`.

Comment: `nopostdot` part possibly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94502 and the `nonumberlist` part is possibly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13162